# Radio Button Selection Fires JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, radio-group

I want the function to trigger another function based on which radio input is selected/checked.  My function does not appear to be "seeing" the radio button check event.  **What am I doing wrong?**  This is just an extract, the functions chartAmount() and chartPercent() are defined in the originals.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Connect Radio Sliders to JS</title> 
    <script src="http://public.tableausoftware.com/javascripts/api/tableau_v8.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="semantic.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Radio Buttons fire JS Function</h1>
    <hr>
    <h3>Problem/Question</h3>
    <hr>
    <p>I want the selection of a radio button to trigger a javascript function.  My attempt does not work, what am I am doing wrong/missing?</p>
    <hr>
    <h3>Note:</h3>
    <p>The HTML and JS are extracted from a larger filet that include all approriate links to reuqired resources.  The two functions chartAmount() and chartPercent() are defined in the larger document.</p>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <div class="ui form">
          <div class="grouped fields">
            <label>Radio Button Select</label>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui slider checkbox">
                        <input type="radio" name="charttype" checked="checked" value="percent">
                        <label>Amount by Year</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="ui slider checkbox">
                        <input type="radio" name="charttype" value="amount">
                        <label>Percent by Year</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <script>
            $('.field').click(function() {
                if($("input[value='Amount']").is(':checked')) { chartAmount(); }
                if($("input[value='Percent']").is(':checked')) { chartPercent(); }
            })
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectors are case sensitive.  You should use:

```
$('.field').click(function() {
    if($("input[value='amount']").is(':checked')) { chartAmount(); }
    if($("input[value='percent']").is(':checked')) { chartPercent(); }
})
```

Edit to add:

You might also want to consider binding to the change event for `input[type="radio"]` instead.  You also need to tie your labels to the corresponding inputs, otherwise they provide no value.

Something more like this:

Javascript:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function() { 
    if($("input[value='amount']").is(':checked')) { chartAmount(); }
    if($("input[value='percent']").is(':checked')) { chartPercent(); }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grouped fields">
    Radio Button Select
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui slider checkbox">
            <label><input type="radio" name="charttype" checked="checked" value="percent"> Amount by Year</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui slider checkbox">
            <label><input type="radio" name="charttype" value="amount"> Percent by Year</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle example:  https://jsfiddle.net/eo0e4r63/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the .change function to detect whenever the choice from the radio buttons is changed.

```
   $("input:radio[name='charttype']").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "percent"){
            chartPercent();
        }   
        else if($(this).val() == "amount"){
            chartAmount();
        }
    });
```

JSFiddle : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/g2grhb8f/)